# Division with if condition

Tags: ruby

I just start learning ruby with an online course and in my very first exercise, I can't complete the challenge. I have to create functions to sum, subtract, multiply and divide that meet the specs conditions.

For the division, I need to check if it will divide per 0 or not, give the result or a warning. My code is

```
def divisao(primeiro_numero, segundo_numero)
    if segundo_numero > 0
        primeiro_numero / segundo_numero
    else
        puts 'Opa! Zero como divisor'
end
```

But when I run the specs, I get the following warning

```
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

I have changed all the functions, but this one doesn't seem to work. 
I added the complete functions and specs file here:https://gist.github.com/isafloriano/86c170400b2f5fc63dc5e8edd8913525

Can anyone give me a clue why this doesn't work?

Comment: Does your function support only positive number?

Comment: Your link doesn't work. Please read "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"
and "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)". We need the minimal code in the question that demonstrates the problem you're having. If you want to use a method, then add code to run the method. Yes, we can easily add that but it's what you are supposed to do. We need the specs file in the question itself also. Links rot and break and without that information the question is worthless to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just missing the `end` of the if-else block:

```
def divisao(primeiro_numero, segundo_numero)
  if segundo_numero > 0
    primeiro_numero / segundo_numero
  else
    puts 'Opa! Zero como divisor'
  end # <= this one was missing
end
```

Some suggestion:

- Use English method and variable names. That makes it easier for others to understand your code and to help you.
- Try to follow common Ruby conventions right from the start. Ruby code is indented with two spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a compact way to write your four methods.

```
def add(n1, n2)
  f(n1, n2, :+)
end

def subtract(n1, n2)
  f(n1, n2, :-)
end

def multiply(n1, n2)
  f(n1, n2, :*)
end

def divide(n1, n2)
  if n2.zero?
    puts "Zero-divide error"
    return nil
  end
  f(n1, n2, :/)
end
```

```
def f(n1, n2, op)
   n1.public_send(op, n2)
end
```

```
add(3, 7)         #=> 10 
add(5, 7.2)       #=> 12.2 

subtract(4, 8)    #=> -4 
subtract(6.1, 3)  #=> 3.0999999999999996 

multiply(2, 6)    #=> 12 
multiply(1.0, 6)  #=> 6.0 

divide(4, 0)      #=> nil
Zero-divide error
divide(4, 0.0)    #=> nil
Zero-divide error
divide(4, 2)      #=> 2 
divide(5, 2)      #=> 2 
divide(5, 2.0)    #=> 2.5
```

See [Object#public_send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send).